# Simplifying function on ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-animate

Heloo, I'd like to make an animation in my program. I've tried a function and its worked. But, this function is gonna be very very long if I continue. Here is my function.

```
if(jalan) 
    {
        dt1 += t;
        s1 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt1);
        P1.y = s01 + s1;
        var delay1:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
        delay1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay1);
        delay1.start();
        function f_delay1(event:TimerEvent)
        {
            dt2 += t;
            s2 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt2);
            P2.y = s02 + s2;
            var delay2:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
            delay2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay2);
            delay2.start();
            function f_delay2(event:TimerEvent)
            {
                dt3 += t;
                s3 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt3);
                P3.y = s03 + s3;
                var delay3:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                delay3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay3);
                delay3.start();
                function f_delay3(event:TimerEvent)
                {
                    dt4 += t;
                    s4 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt4);
                    P4.y = s04 + s4;
                    var delay4:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                    delay4.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay4);
                    delay4.start();
                    function f_delay4(event:TimerEvent)
                    {
                        dt5 += t;
                        s5 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt5);
                        P5.y = s05 + s5;
                        var delay5:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                        delay5.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay5);
                        delay5.start();
                        function f_delay5(event:TimerEvent)
                        {
                            dt6 += t;
                            s6 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt6);
                            P6.y = s06 + s6;
                            var delay6:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                            delay6.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay6);
                            delay6.start();
                            function f_delay6(event:TimerEvent)
                            {
                                dt7 += t;
                                s7 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt7);
                                P7.y = s07 + s7;
                                var delay7:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                                delay7.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay7);
                                delay7.start();
                                function f_delay7(event:TimerEvent)
                                {
                                    dt8 += t;
                                    s8 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt8);
                                    P8.y = s08 + s8;
                                    var delay8:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                                    delay8.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay8);
                                    delay8.start();
                                    function f_delay8(event:TimerEvent)
                                    {
                                        dt9 += t;
                                        s9 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt9);
                                        P9.y = s09 + s9;
                                        var delay9:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                                        delay9.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay9);
                                        delay9.start();
                                        function f_delay9(event:TimerEvent)
                                        {
                                            dt10 += t;
                                            s10 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt10);
                                            P10.y = s010 + s10;
                                            var delay10:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                                            delay10.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay10);
                                            delay10.start();
                                            function f_delay10(event:TimerEvent)
                                            {
                                                dt11 += t;
                                                s11 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt11);
                                                P11.y = s011 + s11;
                                                var delay11:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
                                                delay11.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,f_delay11);
                                                delay11.start();
                                                function f_delay11(event:TimerEvent)
                                                {
                                                    dt12 += t;
                                                    s12 = -A*Math.sin(w*dt12);
                                                    P12.y = s012 + s12;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there another function that can simplify this function?
Thanks

Making some wave animation by vibrating some particles in a pattern with delay in each particle

Answer (score 1):

When processing data in a similar manner, it is always about **Array**s and loops, even if there is a need for delay between loop iterations.

Something like that, I guess. Not tested, but the idea should be clear.

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

// Array of Arrays
var Sequence:Array =
[
    {dt:dt1, P:P1, s0:s01},
    {dt:dt2, P:P2, s0:s02},
    {dt:dt3, P:P3, s0:s03},
    {dt:dt4, P:P4, s0:s04},
    {dt:dt5, P:P5, s0:s05},
    {dt:dt6, P:P6, s0:s06},
    {dt:dt7, P:P7, s0:s07},
    {dt:dt8, P:P8, s0:s08},
    {dt:dt9, P:P9, s0:s09},
    {dt:dt10, P:P10, s0:s010},
    {dt:dt11, P:P11, s0:s011},
];

function onNext(index:int = 0):void
{
    // Checking, if there anything left on the Sequence to do.
    if (index >= Sequence.length)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    // Extract the first tuple of data.
    var aData:Object = Sequence[index];
    
    // Your initial logic here.
    aData.dt += t;
    aData.P.y = aData.s0 - A * Math.sin(w * aData.dt);
    
    // Wait before addressing the next particle.
    setTimeout(onNext, 1000, index + 1);
}

if (jalan)
{
    // The initial call.
    onNext();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems a good idea

I've tried your function in my program. Adding some required variables also has been done. The program was working without error, but the particles didn't start to move. What's the problem?

Comment: First of all, **trace** to debug if the **onNext** is called. Second, **trace** if the data it works with is correct. The thing is, the data in **Sequence** is recorded at the moment of its creation, while the data in your original code is picked at the moment you work with them. They just might be different.

Comment: I've traced "dt1" variable, and it's constant along the program running. That's the problem. We had written "dt += t;", but why it wasn't increase?

Comment: As I already pointed out above, the data is written to the **Array** upon its creation, and does not track the original variables/values. I've edited the answer so that it works with the persistent **Array** data and modifies them. Also, traded **Timer** for **setTimeout** in need to pass an additional argument. Just don't re-create the **Sequence** because you would erase the said persistence.

Comment: Okayy it's work, great thanks to u :)